# Strange locked-out situation, where previous answers don't work

Tags: boot, grub2

I made a stupid chmod mistake and forgot my username, so am locked out of my ubuntu laptop. Previous answers don't help.
I tried holding down the shift key when it started up, and instead of going to grub boot menu, I got an error message about a cable not working, and press any key to boot. Pressing any key takes me back to needing to remember the username...
The only cable connected to the laptop is the power cord.
I ran checks before booting, and the only problem was the battery being near it's end of life.
It's an older machine, an old Dell latitude. Ubuntu has acted weird since it upgraded, but now I can't even get into it.

Comment: use a live session to boot from it, mount the hard disk and your login name is shown when you do `ls /{mountpoint}/home/` or when you open the disk in the filemanager.  You can also use this method to backup your personal files and to re-install your system.

Comment: Try graphical install option(if it work) and by that you can mount the hard disk. And, you can even check /etc/passwd file. There you will have list of all the user. Probably, you can identify from there.

Comment: Thank you both! I will try that.